# Почему окно обрезается?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я сделал разметку для страницы моего приложение, но почему то обрезается окно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="WpfApp21.Pages.LoginPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp21.Pages"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp21.ViewModels"
Title="LoginPage"
d:DesignHeight="250"
d:DesignWidth="400"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="LoginPageViewModel" Source="{StaticResource ViewModelLocator}" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <Style
        x:Key="PlaceholderTextBoxStyle"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
        TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="border"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="textBlock"
                                Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                            <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.56" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7EB4EA" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF569DE5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="49*"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="140*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock
        
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="24"
        Text="Авторизация" />

    <Button
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="5,5,5,5"
        Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
        Content="Войти" />


    <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Логин" />
            <TextBox
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                Style="{StaticResource PlaceholderTextBoxStyle}"
                Tag="Логин" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Пароль" />
            <TextBox
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                Style="{StaticResource PlaceholderTextBoxStyle}"
                Tag="Пароль" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Двуфакторный код" />
            <TextBox
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                Style="{StaticResource PlaceholderTextBoxStyle}"
                Tag="Двухфакторный код(при наличии)" />

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Размер основного окна такой-же, как и в d:DesignWidth и d:DesignHeight

Comment: `Height="140*"` уберите искусственное огрничение, пусть контролы занимают столько места, сколько им нужно

Comment: это обрезало окно еще сильнее. оставил прросто row defenition